# ThreeJS CSS 3D Sprite Randomize

Tags: javascript, html, css, three.js

I'm having a little bit of trouble; I am trying to adapt *ThreeJS CSS 3D Sprite* so that it use an **array of images** for the sprites. The original is [here](https://github.com/mrdoob/three.js/blob/dev/examples/css3d_sprites.html). Here is my code:

```
  ...
  var image = document.createElement( 'img' );
  image.addEventListener( 'load', function ( event ) {
    for ( var i = 0; i < particlesTotal; i ++ ) {
      var object = new THREE.CSS3DSprite( image.cloneNode() );
      object.position.x = Math.random() * 4000 - 2000,
      object.position.y = Math.random() * 4000 - 2000,
      object.position.z = Math.random() * 4000 - 2000;
      scene.add( object );
      objects.push( object );
    }
    transition();
  }, false );
  // image.src = 'assets/img/textures/sprite.png';

  /* Randomize Images
  ============================================= */
  var imagesArray = ['assets/img/textures/orb_makro.png','assets/img/textures/orb_tiger_brands.png','assets/img/textures/orb_unilever.png'];)
  var num = Math.floor(Math.random() * 3) + 1 ;
  image.src = imagesArray[num];

  ...
```

I think part of the problem is that takes an instance of one image and then multiplies it, that's where I am getting stuck. Many thanks!!

Comment: To pick a random URL from the array you can use: `var num = Math.floor(Math.random() * imagesArray.length);` instead (remember base-0 so don't add +1 to the result).

Comment: I think part of the problem is that it is creating a single image element. I'm trying to figure out how to create multiple images from an array

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To pick a random image for the 3D sprite you would first preload all the images:

```
var imagesArray = [];
var urlArray = ['assets/img/textures/orb_makro.png',
                'assets/img/textures/orb_tiger_brands.png',
                'assets/img/textures/orb_unilever.png'];
var count = urlArray.length;

// load all images asynchronously
urlArray.forEach(function(url) {
  var img = new Image;
  img.onload = handler;   // todo: also add handler for onerror/onabort
  img.src = url;
  imagesArray.push(img);  // store image to preloaded array
});

function handler() {
  if (!--count) setup();  // when all images are loaded, go to setup
}
```

In the setup section we can now pick a random image from the preloaded array just adding and modifying a line:

```
// ...
for ( var i = 0; i < particlesTotal; i++ ) {
  var index = (Math.random() * imagesArray.length)|0; // random index
  var object = new THREE.CSS3DSprite( imagesArray[index].cloneNode() );
  object.position.set(Math.random() * 4000 - 2000,
                      Math.random() * 4000 - 2000,
                      Math.random() * 4000 - 2000);
  scene.add( object);
  objects.push( object );
}
// ...
```

You could as an option skip the random index step since the positions are random and just cycle through the array:

```
var object = new THREE.CSS3DSprite( imagesArray[i % imagesArray.length].cloneNode() );
```

Comment: thank you so much! I can't tell what this mean :)) was struggling with this for ages! Just one correction change `scene.push` to `scene.add`.